# Can you re-number the order of artboards in Illustrator CS4?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

I use illustrator with multiple artboards to design website layouts. Often I start at the beginning (what I think is the beginning at the time) and get 15 pages deep. Then I realize that I need to add another page at the beginning. I want this page to be page 1. Is this possible to do without physically moving all the elements in a page one by one?

Comment: I am using CS4 and ran into this problem. After reviewing the above answers, I was not able to resolve the issue for whatever reason using the above methods. So, I had 6 pages and needed to add blank page between pages 1 and 2. So I deleted artboards 2-6 but left the artwork in place. When I added the new artboards, number 2 was in the proper place. Make sense?

Answer (score 29):

It is possible in CS5.1 - late response but was looking for another answer and stumbled on  this question.

In the `Artboards panel` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>) you can re order the artboards listed by dragging a row up or down to the required position.  This renumbers the artboards.  Great for the purposes of exporting, no more reordering pdf pages each time.

[image]

Artboards are given a default name reflecting the initial number but this is just a label - you can rename an artboard either when the artboard tool is active by clicking the label of the actual artboard or using artboards panel options menu.

Moving them around so that they are visually ordered is a bit of a pain - you can use the artboard tool to move them which best done zoomed out but if you stop dragging while over another artboard it will pick up all art work that is under it when you start dragging again (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to the rescue).

Artboards can also be positioned while the artboard tool is active using the transform panel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + O didn't seem to work for me, but Windows > Artboards works.

Comment: Oh my god, where has this tip been all my life? In all my years using Illustrator, I never knew you could do this. THANK YOU!

Comment: This should not have so many up votes.  It doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 5):

this is a very old post, but some users still using CS4, may come across this post in the future...

here's a script I wrote in 2012.

click on the Artboard tool before running, to see the Artboard Indexes. In this scenario, lets pretend we had 3 artboards and we need to add a 4th one, and insert it between 1 and 2, so page 4 becomes 2, page 2 becomes 3, and page 3 becomes 4.

[image]

1. we fire up the script
2. move artboard 4, underneath artboard 1
3. press Re Arrange button

[image]

the new order is now 1,4,2,3

[image]

[Download re-Arrange Artboards Script v2](http://aiscripts.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/reArrangeArtboards_v2.zip)

Comment: I was just about to write this script myself, but I stumbled on your post first. And unlike the answer with the most votes;  this actually answers the OP's question.  Nice work!

Comment: It looked very promising. Unfortunately, I get a blank box with no artboard inside : (

Answer (score 2):

There isn't currently a way to renumber artboards in AI, so you'd have to do some kind of workaround no matter what. Possibly you export to Illustrator PDF then Place the pages on new artboards in a new document, but I don't see that would be faster than simply moving the contents of the artboards.

Comment: Or create a new Illustrator document and drag everything over a page at a time. Or possibly work in InDesign. :)

Comment: Ah thats what I was afraid of!! I love the new features in illustrator, but that is one flaw me for! Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I've researched this and found no real answer to re-numbering...however you can delete them and re-draw them in the sequence you prefer....Works like a charm!

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on Window - Artboards, a new tab appears at the bottom right hand navigation where 'Layers' is. You can drag and drop to re-order the art boards here.

[image: Re-order Artboards Window]

Comment: Note.. question is asking about **CS4** The Artboard Panel does not exist in CS4.

Answer (score 0):

I received 12 CS4 files that each had 3 artboards. The majority had the artboard order as 1,2,3. But a couple of the files had the artboards go 1,3,2. When auto updating in my InDesign layout the artboards would import out of order. So I would go into Illustrator, duplicate the last artboard, and delete the original one I just duplicated. That put them back in order. Basically: original order was 1,3,2. Duplicate 2, which is now artboard 4. Delete the original #2 and now the artboards read 1,2,3.

Comment: The only problem I see with this issue is that if you have 15 artboards and the order is `15, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 1` then this will take some time.

Comment: Yep, it works good on a small scale and with some time and organization involved, with 15 artboards also. With that many artboards, I would make good use of layers - they can be a life and time saver.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out! by accident.

i had 4 artboards and wanted to add one more at the front, for a total of 5. i started by going to document setup, edit artboards. once there, to visualize, i added a new artboard to the left of artboard 1. this new artboard was labeled 5. reading left to right the boards were numbered 5,1,2,3,4. next, i again clicked add new artboard, labeled 6. this time i positioned 6 directly on top of artboard 1. it now read 5,6,2,3,4.

the next step got weird. i simply deleted artboard 6. artboard 6 renumbered itselt to 5, even though 5 already existed. it now read 5,5,2,3,4.

i then exited the edit artboards menu. when i went back to document setup, edit artboards, the numbers were now 4,5,1,2,3. i repeated the above step of covering artboard 1 with a new artboard and then deleting it.

this simply moved the number 1 artboard to the right each time until it eventually went back to the start and read 1,2,3,4,5 from left to right. and voila, no moving artwork but newly numbered boards.

Comment: if you have more than 5 artboards this will take some time...

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to click on the right icon within the Artboard Toolbox which shows the bounding box of the artboard. Now that you've identified its location. Hit Escape to close the dialogue box.

Drag the artboard in the toolbox to the numeric position you want. Then, rename that artboard. You may have to add a *.1 extension to the name to differentiate it temporarily. Do the same for each artboard you need to change. The problem is that when it comes to Exporting and naming to Share with colleagues, if you don't get that Artboard order fixed, your Artboards will not be in the order you want. Its a PITA that Devs need to think about a better, cleaner solution. It sucks when you realize that you've got a few pages out of order. I think its a result of auto rearranging.