# Is there a way to automate reversing the order of artboards in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, artboard, illustrator-scripting

Is there a way to reverse the order of artboards so that pages 1 2 3 4 become 4 3 2 1 ? I am trying to extract the English pages from a bilingual booklet and changing each artboard manually is not the most efficient.

(Looking for automation solution)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3619/can-you-re-number-the-order-of-artboards-in-illustrator-cs4)

Comment: @Cai Thanks but not quite what I'm looking for, it works good for repositioning a single artboard, I want to reverse all at once.

Comment: why don't you save your AI file as PDF and open it with Acrobat and revers the order of the pages ? because Illustrator doesn't preserve an order to your artboard as it cloud be freely re positioned.

Comment: Ok fair enough, I think scripting may be your only option. I can't find anything though.

Comment: @hsawires Illustrator does preserve artboard order, and the position of artboards has nothing to do with their order. That's the problem.

Comment: yes sure @CaiMorris in its pannel ... but you cant preserve order visually  ... I mean in the panel it could be 1 2 3 4 but visually it could be anything from left to right or from bottom to up. tell me if I a wrong.

Comment: Oh ok @hsawires, I misunderstood your comment. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this script,

```
// reverseArtboardsOrder.jsx
// carlos canto
// http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64865/is-there-a-way-to-automate-reversing-the-order-of-artboards-in-illustrator

function reverseArboardsOrder () {
    var idoc = app.activeDocument;
    var abs = idoc.artboards;
    var abcount = abs.length; 

    var abNames = [];    
    var abRects = [];

    for (i=0; i<abcount; i++) {
        abNames[i] = abs[i].name; 
        abRects[i] = abs[i].artboardRect;
    }

    for (j=0, k=abcount-1; j<abcount; j++, k--) {
        var abRect = abRects[k]; 
        idoc.artboards.remove(k); 
        var newab = idoc.artboards.add(abRect);
        newab.name = abNames[k]; 
    }
    idoc.rearrangeArtboards();
}

reverseArboardsOrder();
```

Comment: If you don't want to visually reorder the artboards (I don't think that's what the question is asking for) just reverse the order in the artboards panel, remove the call to rearrangeArtboards()

Comment: Hi Cai, I thought the OP wanted to reverse the visual order as well, since he wasn't happy with the result of the first script you linked in your first comment

Comment: Thanks Carlos! The script works beautifully, and yes although it was not clear, rearranging the visual order as well is logical. Much appreciated and a happy new year :)